# Sort Nautilus data by text after a delimiter

Tags: nautilus

I have quite a few .epub files that use the naming convention:

**Bookname - Author.epub**

How do I sort these files in Nautilus by Author, (or the word after the dash -).

I would like to be able to cut and paste all of the .epub files by a certain Author to a folder with the Authors name.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: that is not possible.

- You can use "Select items matching" to select all the files that match your criteria. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. In the resulting dialog, provide a wildcard match, e.g. `*- Author name.epub`, which would select all matching file names.
- Alternatively, the search function allows to quickly retrieve all files that contain a certain string, e.g. "Author". The search function by default is recursive: it searches the current folder and all folders below. In "Preferences", "Search & Preview" tab, you can disable the search in subfolders.